# How to get the last modifier of files in Google Drive using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

Here's the code:

```
// List files inside the folder
var files = childFolder.getFiles();
while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
  var childFile = files.next();
  // Logger.log("File Name: " + childFile.getName());
  data = [ 
    parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + 
    childFile.getName(),
    childFile.getName(),
    childFile.getDateCreated(),
    childFile.getUrl(),
    childFile.getLastUpdated(),
    childFile.getDescription(),
    childFile.getEditors(),
    childFile.getSize()
  ];
  // Write
  sheet.appendRow(data);
}
```

*Can you help me know what is the code in getting the last user who modifies  the file? ".getEditors" is not the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

This uses version 2 of the Drive API:

```
function driveActivity() {
  var options={}
  var list=Drive.Changes.list();
  var html="";
  var data=JSON.parse(list);
  for(var i=0;i<data.items.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><strong>Title:</strong> %s <strong>Id:</strong> %s <strong>Date:</strong> %s <strong>User:</strong> %s',data.items[i].file.title,data.items[i].fileId,data.items[i].modificationDate,data.items[i].file.lastModifyingUserName);
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(1200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Mods');
}
```

Don't Forget to enable it:

[image]

- [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/changes/list?apix_params=%7B%22pageToken%22%3A%22112648%22%7D)

Comment: Thanks for the help Cooper, However, enabling the v2  in Drive API is not allowed here at work. Is there any other way to get the last user who modified the file? Is there a code like my original code ".getLastUpdated" something like that? My original code is working but it can't get the last user who modified the file.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I have an update. I already enabled the v2 in Drive API. However, I am getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "title" from undefined."

Comment: You have to add the drive API to your script in the Resources dialog and you have to enable it at the developers console. It’s an advanced api.

Comment: I'm sorry but your last answer, is it for the error? because the API was already enabled at the developers console.

Comment: Actually, I just tried to use the code you've shared and when I run it this is the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "title" from undefined." I just want to how it works.

Comment: Well then I suspect that you don't have Drive API enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is the screenshot: [API Enabled][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OXvO.png is this correct?

Actually, I have checked other answers then I saw that it needs to be enabled in Google Developer's Console both Drive API and Drive SDK but I can't find it on my Developer's Console.